# linear map $O:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ with $m<n$ with associated matrix $O^TO=I_{m\times m}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $O$ be a $n$ by $m$ matrix with $m<n$ such that $O^TO=I_{m\times m}$. Then what is the geometric interpretation of the linear map associated to the matrix $O$? I know that if $O$ was a square matrix it would be the composition of a rotation and a reflexion, so I guess that when $m<n$ we also have some kind of embedding but I can't tell more than this.

Comment: the fact that $P:=OO^T$ is an orthogonal projection may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$\Omega:=O^T \times O=I_{m\times m} \tag{1}$$

Let us write:

$$O=\begin{pmatrix}\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
C_1&C_2&\cdots&C_m\\
\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\end{pmatrix}$$

Due to the fact that the product in (1) is "lines of the first matrix times columns on the second matrix, relationship (1) expresses that $\Omega$ is a matrix of dot products with:

$$\Omega_{ij}=C_i . C_j=0 \ \ \text{if} \ \  i \ne j$$

$$\Omega_{ii}=C_i . C_i = \|C_i\|^2=1$$

Therefore, the conclusion is that property (1) means that the columns $C_i$ of $O$ constitute an orthonormal system, but not an orthonormal basis because we have only $m<n$ elements.

It is difficult to say something more, in particular as a transformation matrix...